# Views 3 - Create an archive for a given type grouped by year, then split in to months

Tags: views

I am trying to create an archive in Views 3 (Drupal 7) to use a filter for a given type to sort in to a list of nodes grouped in to Months, but then they are grouped in to Year:

```
Node Type
  |-Year
    |-September (node count)
    |-August (node count)
      ...
    |-February (node count)
    |-January (node count)
  |-Year
    |-December (node count)
    |-November (node count)
    |-October (node count)
```

I have looked at the default Archive view template, but that just groups by month (i.e. September 2012 (node count))

If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have anyone figured out how to do this. I'd be interested in finding out how to do this as well using views.